# TYPO3: replace string in variable

Tags: templates, replace, typo3

Consider the following TYPO3 HTML template snippet:

```
<button type="button"> {my_controller_assigned_variable} </button>
```

I need something like

```
{my_controller_assigned_variable}.replace("_", " ")
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a replace viewhelper in the [vhs extensions](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/1.3.2/Format/ReplaceViewHelper.html), but you can also use the default cObject viewhelper and do the replace with TypoScript:

Fluid template:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.replaceUnderscore">{my_controller_assigned_variable}</f:cObject
```

TypoScript:

```
lib.replaceUnderscore = TEXT
lib.replaceUnderscore {
  current = 1
  stdWrap.replacement {
    10 {
        search = _
        replace.char = 32
    }
  }
}
```

I didn't test this, but I've done something similar in the past, so it should work. You can find more on the cObject viewhelper [here](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/CObject.html) and the replacement TypoScript [here](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Replacement.html)

Comment: using that cObject code results in an empty button ...?

Comment: ohhh you mean I have to define lib.replaceUnderscore too, okay I'll check

Comment: sorry for that stupid question but where do I need to put that lib.replaceUnderscore code?

Comment: okay got it, it works! I've put the code into my main typoscript template. however I do not find "current" in the reference of TEXT, what does it do?

Comment: current sets the value to the "current" value. The cObject viewhelper sets its contents as the "current" value, so it's the value of your variable. Current is part of [stdWrap](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Stdwrap/Index.html#current)

Comment: so let's say my_controller_assigned contains "hello_joe". then the cObject viewhelper comes along and sets current = "hello_joe" as you say? but then your code sets current = 1 and thereby overrides it? I don't get it :/

Comment: Normally on a `TEXT` you have `value = foo`. What `current = 1` does is set `value` to the "current" value, which in your example is "hello_joe"